# The code working only without IF

Tags: php

```html
$sqlCommand="SELECT materials.id,materials.code,materials.category, materials.material_name,
sum(if(transactions.transaction_type='Receive' AND transactions.date <='2015-12-31' ,transactions.quantity,0))
-(sum(if(transactions.transaction_type='issue' AND transactions.date <='2015-12-31' ,transactions.quantity,0)))
 as OP_balance,
FROM materials INNER JOIN transactions  ON materials.code=transactions.code Group By materials.id";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCommand);
?>
<tbody>
<?php if(isset($_POST["search"])){ while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn,$query)){
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['code']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['category']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['material_name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['OP_balance']; ?></td> 
</tr> <? }}  else{ echo "No data";}
?>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="submit" name="search" qvalue="Search"/>
  <p><label for="from_date">from Date:</label><input type="date" name="from_date" value="<?="$from_date"?>" /></p>
  <p><label for="to_date">To Date:</label><input type="date" name="to_date" value="<?="$to_date"?>" /></p> 
</form>
```

[This code is working without adding IF statement. But when I use IF it returns "No data." Please, help me finding out the mistake and where to enter the IF condition?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVvEx.png)

Comment: Copy-paste the code here instead of linking to image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an action on your form. The form has to submit to somewhere, fx.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">...</form>
```

And in the future, it's recommended to copy/paste your code in the question to make it easier to look at :-)